# Detecting degeneracy in triangulations that causes matplotlib to crash?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I built a plot over roads graph and am trying to interpolate the data in a raster, but some nodes cause triangulation error.

Earlier I noticed and fixed a problem when multiple points sticked in one place on a graph and this caused triangulation error. Now these duplicates are removed, but still some sets of points make it crash.

I did not manage to detect what in particular. When I order them by a coordinate and remove either half, the problem disappears.

I suspect some points be standing in one line close enough that the triangulator algorithm tries to build a triangle of them and crashes. But have not found them yet.

What is a way to find the set of points causing the error?

Here's the code, it comes from [python-osrm](https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm/blob/b3fb300348e069e5f556710e2dabb18d550684da/osrm/extra.py#L73) package which copies it from [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html) in matplotlib:

```
import csv
import matplotlib
import itertools
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata


with open('/tmp/triangle.csv') as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    matrix = [map(float, r) for r in rd]

x, y, z = zip(*matrix)

minx = np.nanmin(x)
miny = np.nanmin(y)
maxx = np.nanmax(x)
maxy = np.nanmax(y)

xi = np.linspace(minx, maxx, 400)
yi = np.linspace(miny, maxy, 400)
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
```

Here's the data: https://pastebin.com/TWz3vNbC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use another interpolation algorithm. CubicTriInterpolator can process a mesh of collinear points.

```
minx = np.nanmin(x)
miny = np.nanmin(y)
maxx = np.nanmax(x)
maxy = np.nanmax(y)

# Assuming we want a square grid for the interpolation
xi = np.linspace(minx, maxx, 400)
yi = np.linspace(miny, maxy, 400)

# make all combinations of Xi and Yi (400*400), then unwrap it in one line (in 2 rows (x, y) by 160k)
ci = np.reshape(np.meshgrid(xi, yi), (2, 160000))

triang = Triangulation(x, y)
interp = CubicTriInterpolator(triang, z, kind='geom')

# interpolate values, then re-wrap it into 400 by 400 for contourf (it requires a grid like pixels)
zi = np.reshape(interp(*ci), (400, 400))

collec_poly = plt.contourf(
    xi, yi, zi, levels, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
    vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max(), alpha=0.35
    )
```